# sls offline GET /users (λ: getUsers) ✖ ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/reponame.go'

Tags: go, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

While using serverless offline for Golang.
On sending any request from Postman
GET /users (λ: getUsers)
✖ ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/Desktop/Reponame.go'
However the same works fine while using sls offline --useDocker

Comment: I'm having an exact same issue, works with `--useDocker`